# Java HTTP process for 'streaming' video file

Tags: java, http, video, http-headers

I am creating a Java application which 'streams' a video file over http to a browser (currently Chrome v24.x). This video is sent to FFmpeg and the output of this is sent over HTTP.

Now, once the file is completely encoded the file is served using chunked transfer, and responding to range requests. Example headers:

#### Request

```
GET /file/9fe6b502-c127-47c2-b6d2-83ea58676a8d HTTP/1.1 : Host: localhost:1234 : Connection: keep-alive : Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0 : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17 : Accept: */* : Referer: http://localhost:1234/media/9fe6b502-c127-47c2-b6d2-83ea58676a8d : Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 : Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 : Cookie: plushContainerWidth=100%25; plushNoTopMenu=0 : Range: bytes=0- :
```

#### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content : Connection: close : Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 14:51:52 GMT : Content-Type: video/mp4 : Etag: "9fe6b502-c127-47c2-b6d2-83ea58676a8d" : Accept-Ranges: bytes : Content-Range: bytes 0-625825/625826 : Content-Length: 625826 : Transfer-Encoding: chunked :
```

Data sent is 625826 bytes, excluding header data and chunked overhead.

Now, this works just fine!

The trouble is when the GET request happens before the file encoding has completed. I have tried to start sending the file straight away, over HTTP, using just chunked transfer with no content length attributes or ranges because they are not currently known. This causes the browser to wait for the full file (and not start playing until the transfer has completed). In addition, when the file transfer is completed, the browser reports a video error that the file could not be played. Example headers:

#### Request

```
Request : GET /file/9fe6b502-c127-47c2-b6d2-83ea58676a8d HTTP/1.1 : Host: localhost:1234 : Connection: keep-alive : Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0 : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17 : Accept: */* : Referer: http://localhost:1234/media/9fe6b502-c127-47c2-b6d2-83ea58676a8d : Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 : Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 : Cookie: plushContainerWidth=100%25; plushNoTopMenu=0 : Range: bytes=0-
```

#### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK : Connection: close : Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 14:51:29 GMT : Content-Type: video/mp4 : Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Data sent is 625826 bytes, excluding header data and chunked overhead.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going wrong, or how to start playing a video without knowing the full length of the file?

Thanks for your time,

James.

//EDIT

As the request for the incomplete file states 'Range: bytes=0-' - can I reply with a partial content of 'n' bytes (say, 1000 bytes) with Content-Range: bytes 0-999/* ?

//EDIT 2
As requested, here is my code for outputting the file. This is condensed as the code actually spans several classes.

```
File f = new File(_filename);
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
ChunkedOutputStream cos = new ChunkedOutputStream(_out, 1024 * 100);
byte[] bytes;

while (true){
    lBufferSizeMax = Math.min(lBufferSize, fc.length() - lCompleted);
    bytes = new byte[(int)lBufferSizeMax];

    lCurrentRead = fc.read(bytes);
    if (lCurrentRead == 0){
        break;
    }

    cos.write(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code of how you write to `OutputStream` video-file contents.

Comment: It's not the output code, that works fine as the same code is used for outputting video before and after transcoding is complete. This is a question around headers, and what the browser expects to happen given requests and how range requests work with unknown file sizes.

Comment: Programmically you should set size of file, which you are writing to `outputStream`, '-1'.

Comment: Thanks, Andremoniy - maybe it is the output code after all! I have included the code. Would you be able to give an example how I set the size as per your comment? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: What needs to be clarified here is that it isn't the browser playing the video stream, it is instead a browser plugin (such as Media Player, etc.).  Can you clarify this?  Perhaps the plugin needs the URL in a certain format? http://fmj-sf.net/fmj/getting_started.php

Comment: It is mpeg4 so I believe Chrome is playing the file natively. I did however, try playing the URL in Windows MP and the result is the same; it plays once transcoded and the file length is known, but does not play during transcoding and the file length cannot be sent in a header.

Comment: @JAC2703 show us complete code where you are writing `content-type` and so on

Comment: Why don't you encode all your files before firing up the http service? Are they rapidly changing, or even delivering live content?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that `ffmpeg` is likely to rewrite portions of the file when encoding is ending.  That means the metadata in the video file will be incomplete until the very end so there is no use trying to stream the beginning of the file before that time.  You can check with replacing the output filename in your `ffmpeg` command line with a single dash and redirect stdout to a file.  Instead of `ffmpeg ... out.mov` do `ffmpeg ... - > out.mov`.  If you get an error message saying the format needs seekable output you are affected.

I have done almost exactly what you are trying to do, the results are in my [Git repo](http://forkalsrud.org:8080/~knut/gitweb.cgi?p=album.git;a=tree;f=src/main/java/org/forkalsrud/album/video;hb=HEAD).  The container format I use, where I can play games with the metadata, is FLV.  Unfortunately that is not what the iPad/iPhone devices out there like to see.

Comment: Knut, you are absolutely correct! I found this out myself doing a crude vi compare - the beginning of the output file changes during encoding. FLV isn't really an option, however that may change as my options are becoming more limited. I may have to take gyabraham's approach.